# Javascript FF and IE

Tags: javascript, html

I do have the following script. It is only runing in Chrome. I can't check or activate the checkbox. How can I get it to run in FF and IE?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkHoverButton() {
        var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for( var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            lis[i].onclick = function() {

                var c = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

                if ( c.checked ){
                    c.checked = 0;
                    this.style.background = 'white';    
                }
                else{
                    c.checked = 1;
                    this.style.background = '#eceff5';
                }
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<li class="friends-li">
  <span class="green">
     <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" id="form_friend_<?php echo $value; ?>" name="form[friend][]" />
  </span>
  <span class="pink">
    <img id="img_friend_<?php echo $value; ?>" src="">
  </span>
  <span class="blue">
    <label for="form_friend_<?php echo $value;?>" ><?php echo $label;?></label>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `c.checked` to their proper values of `true` and `false`?

Comment: Please tell us what problems occur in IE …

Comment: What is the desired behavior? What isn't working in IE/Firefox?

Comment: I can't get to check or activate the checkbox.

Comment: 0/1/true/false does not matter http://jsfiddle.net/kXcxq/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I assume you are calling `checkHoverButton` somewhere in your code.

The problem is event bubbling.

When you click on the checkbox or the label you are basically cancelling out the action. You need to make sure you are not clicking on those elements.

```
lis[i].onclick = function(e) {

    var clickedOn = (e.srcElement || e.target).nodeName;
    if(clickedOn==="INPUT"||clickedOn==="LABEL") return;     
    var c = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

--Edit--

```
lis[i].onclick = function(e) {

    var clickedOn = (e.srcElement || e.target).nodeName;
    var setState = clickedOn!=="INPUT" && clickedOn!=="LABEL";     
    var c = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    if (setState) {
        c.checked = !c.checked;
    }
    this.style.background = c.checked ? "#eceff5" : "#fff";
};
```

Comment: If you click on the checkbox or the label, the background color doesn't change (since the code after the `if` doesn't get executed) - http://jsfiddle.net/t7RmF/3/ . It works if you click outside of those but in the `li`. I think it needs a little more logic. I feel dumb but I can't figure it out haha

Comment: Do not set the checked state of the checkbox. Basic idea above, I think I got the colors in the right order.

Comment: FYI: I edited the code to show you the basic idea.

Comment: Yeah, I swear I did something like that but it didn't work. But with your changes, it seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/t7RmF/4/ . Hopefully the OP agrees. And yeah, I think the colors are right too

Answer (score 1):

@epascarello approach is very good.

I made a example, maybe it help.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/tT8a3/3/)

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
      checkHandler = function(event){
           event.stopPropagation();
      },
      clickHandler = function (event) {
            var c = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
                  c.onclick = checkHandler;
            if (c.checked) {
                  c.checked = 0;
                  this.classList.remove('darker');
                  this.classList.add('white');
            } else {
                  c.checked = 1;
                  this.classList.remove('white');
                  this.classList.add('darker');
            }
            return false;
      };

for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
      lis[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}
```